# How to do Sign-In with Keycloak with Actions on Google?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to do a sign-in through an action on Google with Google Assistant (on Dialogflow), but it fails for some reason. The sign-in works (it asks for my username and password), then the browser disappears and Google Assistant says the authentication has failed.

- created a new client in Keycloak and added redirect URL and allowed web origins
- Added Account Linking on Actions Console with authorization URL, Client ID, Secret, Token URL (this one might be a wrong url, I tried one but I couldn't find the correct URL)
- Created intents deployed on Firebase with Dialogflow that asks for authentication

```
'use strict';

// Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library.
const {dialogflow, SignIn} = require('actions-on-google');

// Import the firebase-functions package for deployment.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Instantiate the Dialogflow client.
const app = dialogflow({clientId: 'my-client-id', debug: true});

app.intent('sign in', (conv, {person}) => {
    conv.ask(new SignIn(""));
    const name = person.name;
    conv.close('Hello ' + name);
});

// Create a Dialogflow intent with the `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` event.
app.intent('Get Signin', (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const payload = conv.user.profile.payload;
    conv.ask(`I got your account details, ${payload.name}. What do you want to do next?`);
  } else {
    conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next?`);
  }
});

// Set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request.
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Basically when the person triggers the sign in function, it asks for a name. Then it should login, and print the given name again and close the conversation.

The sign in popup just disappears after logging in, and the Google Assistant tells me that something went wrong and that I should try later. No errors were found or atleast, I couldn't find them. I suspect my Account Linking settings are wrong though, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It works now by using the correct Token URL found in https://keycloakurl:keycloakport/auth/realms/realm-name/.well-known/openid-configuration.